# Linq to SQL ('select * from table').Count() vs ("select column from table").Count()

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I am writing some linq queries where I came across following scenario:

I want to fetch records from DB using Linq bases on some filter

Here I want to take all record count also, so I did like below

```
    var queryData = pageContext.ExecuteQuery<MYVIEW>("select * from MYVIEW where {condition} "+ (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query) ? " and " + query : "") + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortString) ? "order by  " + sortString : ""));
            recordCount = queryData.Count();
            result = queryData.Skip(skip)
                    .Take((resultsPerPage).AsQueryable()
                    .ToList();
```

but here I am getting below exception

`The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.`

So I changed my above logic to something like below:

```
    totalRecords = pageContext.ExecuteQuery<View_ManagerExpenseReportSearchList>(selectQuery).Count();

    result = pageContext.ExecuteQuery<View_ManagerExpenseReportSearchList>(selectQuery).Skip(skip)
                        .Take(resultsPerPage).AsQueryable()
                        .ToList();
```

Here **I am just wondering, are there any performance differences** b/w `(select * from table).Count()` vs `(select ID from table).Count()` to fetch total record count

**I want fetch both data and recordCount**

Answer (score 2):

Since you dont read all the data, (pagination logic) you cant count the retrieved List.
So what you have looks Ok.

The only question is should the count be before or after the READ.

I would test both. I would expect the DB can more easily deliver the count after the read in the scenario a page is all items. The page is very likely still in db buffer (Server memory)
and it can return the count easily.

An experienced DBA on the target DB for your expected data volumes is the best person to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only need the record count I recommend
**Select Count (1) from Table**
which will return just one number for record count

**Select * from Table**
will return all columns even if this data is not needed more time for SQL engine to execute the query 
and more bandwidth consumed through the network

**Select Id from Table**
will return Id column only which means less time for SQL engine to execute the query 
and more less bandwidth consumed through the network

Comment: How do you resolve the case where you want the data AND the row count... for, say, allocating a data structure big enough to hold the results?